# syntax error vb.net login using javapi

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to connect to a website using the javapi dll's - (the original procedure which I am adapting was written in Java) which I want to convert to vb.net

what I have for the login proceedure is:

```
Dim url As biz.ritter.javapi.net.URL

Function login() As String
Dim queryString As String = "?"
queryString = queryString + "username=  ~Username"
queryString = queryString + "&password= ~ password "
queryString = queryString + "&Login=Login" 'required for the site

Dim result As String = ""
login = ""
Try

    result = ""
    url.getProtocol.equals(443)
    url.getHost.equals("https://usersite.com")
    url.getPath.equals("/Broker")
    url = New biz.ritter.javapi.net.URL(queryString)

    Dim conn As biz.ritter.javapi.net.URLConnection = url.openConnection()
    'conn.connect() 'connect is not a member of URL connection
    Dim istream As biz.ritter.javapi.io.InputStream = conn.getInputStream()
```

which wont compile as url has not been declared.

when the code is this:

```
url = New biz.ritter.javapi.net.URL(queryString) 
url.getProtocol.equals(443)
url.getHost.equals("https://usersite.com")
url.getPath.equals("/Broker")
```

it compiles normally but when it runs it errors at the first line "unknown protocol" 
I cant declare the protocol before the first line.

same error if I do this:

```
url = New biz.ritter.javapi.net.URL("https://usersite.com/Broker + queryString)
```

There's something I am clearly missing. Unfortunately the documentation is non-existent.

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be `url.getProtocol = 443` etc? (Admittedly all those "get" parts look *distinctly* weird to me.) But calling `equals` isn't going to set properties...

Comment: Sadly no - " getprotocol = 443 " throws a syntax error( as does '="443" '. So how do I set the protocol. That's the big question? Baffling. I've been stuck on this for several days.

Comment: Are there `setProtocol` (etc) methods? (It really is a bizarre-looking API...)